# I want to turn column names into an identifying column in R

Tags: r, reshape2

Hey guys I'm pretty new to R so apologies if this is a dumb question. I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Gelatin Geltrex Combo Control
1   0.761   0.732 0.557   0.723
2   0.704   0.712 0.764   0.540
3   0.580   0.435 0.351   0.537
```

I want to end up with 2 columns; one with the numbers in the row and another column with the current column names as identifiers for the numbers?

Comment: stack(df1) did what I was after. Thanks so much for the help guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we need row/column index we can use `row` and `col` to get the row/column index and create a new dataset with `data.frame`.

```
df2 <- data.frame(Row= c(row(df1)), 
               Col=names(df1)[col(df1)], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

---

Or another option is `melt` from `library(reshape2)`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'matrix' and `melt` to get the row/column names as the first two columns.

```
library(reshape2)
melt(as.matrix(df1))[-3]
```

EDIT:
If we need the `value` and column names as the two columns, just `melt` or use `stack` as @thelatemail mentioned

```
melt(df1)
```

Or `stack` from `base R`

```
stack(df1)
```

Comment: `stack(df1)` I think they want.

Comment: I was reading between the lines, OP should probably clarify exactly what they want.

Comment: @thelatemail Probably you are right.  I thought the OP wanted row/column indices.

Comment: stack(df1) is so cool!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use gather from the tidyr package

```
> library(tidyr)
> df = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6), d = c(7, 8, 9))
> newdf = gather(df, columnNames, values)

  columnNames values
1           a      1
2           a      2
3           a      3
4           b      4
5           b      5
6           b      6
7           d      7
8           d      8
9           d      9
```